# Multiple for loop on Java Set

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have a Map with values and get a Set using Map.keySet method.
In this code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
map.put("1", "a"); 
map.put("2", "b"); 
map.put("3", "c"); 
Set<String> set = map.keySet();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (String key : set) {
        System.out.println(key);
    } 
}
```

am I guaranteed to get

```
1
2
3
```

written out every time? Where is this guarantee written down ? In Javadoc?

EDIT: Actually I don't care about the insertion order, but I care about the fact that using for-each loop on a set will produce the same result over and over, providing that the undelying map does not change (I don't call put, remove).

Comment: Have you executed the code. Is your code compiling and producing the expected output?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please read the EDIT in myquestion

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you want to retrieve in order in which you put key .

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not. But you can use `LinkedHashMap` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and then you will be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

**LinkedHashMap** for order of additionn (put), and **TreeMap** (interface SortedMap) for order of keys.

Comment: I was just thinking that reusing a set object in for-each loop will provide the same result over an over, but I figured it out that the set is still backed by a map. So changing the map also changes the set.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the docs for HashMap state that `keySet()` method does not return a `SortedSet`, it just returns a `Set`, for which the ordering is not guaranteed.

See [HashMap.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29)

Read, in particular: *It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*

Answer (score 0):

No you're not guaranteed a specific order, unless you use a HashMap which implements a custom **set** that can give you this guarantee. The **Set** the HashMap gives you back have an *Iterator()* method which iterates over the elements in "*no particular order*".

Read the java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()

If you want the guarantee that the elements are iterated over **in-order**, i.e. ascending order, use something that implements **SortedMap** like **TreeMap**.

TreeMap Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

On this page you find the *getSet()* method which says "*The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order*".

Comment: Again, I don't want any particular order, I just want the result is the same over multiple invocainion of the for-each loop

Comment: If you loop one time you would get the order you wrote. But if you add an element to the **HashMap** and then loop through it again, you might get that element in between the others in the loop. It has to do with the *.hashcode()* method. You can't be sure were the new elements get put in the **HashMap**.

Comment: You are correct, but I know  where and when the underlying map is changed. It is my code.

Comment: then it's no problem, if you know what output you'll get.